# Rails paperclip get uploaded image path once uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Here is the upload.rb (model)

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
has_attached_file :name, :styles => { :medium => ["600x400>",:jpg], :thumb => ["122x122>",:jpg]}, url: "/post_images/post_:post_id/:style/:filename"

def self.image_url
    "/post_images/post_:post_id/medium/:filename"
end

end
```

How can I get the url of the uploaded file.

My controller:

```
def img_upload
    @image = Upload.new post_id: post_id, name: params[:Filedata]
        if @image.save
          render json: Upload.image_url
        end
end
```

Can any one help me.

Comment: In your view or in your controller?

Comment: @Justin I have included my controller also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller

```
path = @upload.name.url
```

You just need to call `url` to the attachment

for thumb url, just add `(:thumb)`

```
path = @upload.name.url(:thumb)
```

Comment: It is showing path like this `/home/usrname/Documents/site/site_name/public/post_images/post_750/original/Screenshot_from_2013-11-02_00_46_49.png` how it will work in my domain whether it will show the absolute path like above

Comment: ya working fine is it possible to get thumb url. It is showing original url